# How to get notified for SharePoint permission changes on users/groups/documents?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, notifications

Is there a way to detect SharePoint permission changes on users/groups/documents?

I've tried Graph API to get notifications on permission changes in SharePoint Online via Webhook.
But, it seems that could not notify any permission changes.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use remote event receivers in SharePoint. You can configure an event receiver to alert notification while permission changes. Please refer to the following document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint